# Text getting pixels when entered

Tags: text, after-effects

I'm new to after effects.When I enter a text it is getting pixelated and even cannot see and understand. Below I'm attaching a picture of my problem. Thanks.

[image: Image Capture]

Answer (score 0):

Try change the font size, from 12 to say 80 (in the character panel, located on the right in your screenshot).
You also seem to have chosen a very narrow font, it doesnt help.

I should add: this is definitely not the kind of questions to be asked here. You should go to an After Effects user forum, such as https://forums.adobe.com/community/aftereffects_general_discussion?view=discussions&start=0&numResults=30

Comment: Thank you for your time Xavier.I'll be look into your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had the same problem like yours and what I did was I scaled the text way up to 1240x1240 and it resolved my problem. Now my text is very clear!